# Заблокирован файл /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как вернутся к процессу после обрыва ssh соединения? Screen не стоит.

```
$ sudo apt update
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
E: Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
E: Невозможно заблокировать каталог /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: `>>Как вернутся к процессу после обрыва ssh соединения?<<`: вообще говоря — ни как, есть кое-какие хакерские средства (вроде переоткрыть файловые дескрипторы на другой терминал через gdb), но они не для повседневного использования... установить `screen` или `tmux` и пользоваться ими куда более адекватный вариант... Судя по выводу, проблему X можно решить просто убив висящий шелл и/или apt; или дождаться пока это сделает sshd (в зависимости от настроек).

Comment: apt процесс скорее всего мёртв (SIGHUP). Если жив, попробуйте SIGINT, SIGTERM, чтобы убить. Чтобы базу данных пакетов вернуть в рабочее состояние: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. После этого запустите заново apt update (внутри screen, чтобы не повторять процедуру)

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to safely abort apt-get install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/253925/3712)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в данном случае следует не «возвращаться к процессу» (что на практике весьма трудноосуществимо), а «убить» его.

---

> E: Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)

идентификатор процесса, установившего блокировку на файл, можно узнать разными средствами. напимрер:

```
$ sudo fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
/var/lib/apt/lists/lock:  5153
```

или:

```
$ sudo lsof -w /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
apt     5153 root    4uW  REG    8,1        0 131230 /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

в примере это процесс с идентификатором `5153`. его можно «убить»:

```
$ sudo kill -9 5153
```

после этого все блокировки, установленные этим процессом будут сняты.

Comment: Спасибо большое помогли восстановить программу