# Ubuntu 19.04(Disco Dingo)Не удалось получить файл блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

Tags: ubuntu

E: Не удалось получить файл блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
E: Невозможно получить блокировку внешнего интерфейса dpkg (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend); она уже используется другим процессом?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837175/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-var-lib-apt-lists-lock

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Заблокирован файл /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837175/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-var-lib-apt-lists-lock)